# SlackClient Python RTM not capturing messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, slack

I want to write a simple slack bot, which responds a given string to @ mentions, however I am not able to make the official documentation code to work.

I gave all OAuth permission to the bot and have the following code:

```
from slack import RTMClient

@RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
def gravity_bot(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    print(data.get('text'))

try:
    rtm_client = RTMClient(
        token="my_token_auth_code",
        connect_method='rtm.start'
    )
    print("Bot is up and running!")
    rtm_client.start()
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

I think the connection is established, as the "Bot is up and running" message appears, however on the slack channel to bot seems to be offline, also I am not able to get any response in the terminal, not for direct messages, not for channel messages even after inviting the bot to given channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry couldn't let this one go.. I figured it out and here are the steps:

1. Create a "Classic" app in Slack (this is the only way to get the appropriate scopes), just click this link: https://api.slack.com/apps?new_classic_app=1
2. From the "Add features and functionality" tab click on "bots":

[image: Add the bot features]

3. Click the "Add Legacy Bot User" button (this will add the "rtm.stream" scope that you need, but that you cannot add manually)

[image: Legacy bot user]

4. From the basic information page, install your app in a workspace
5. From the OAuth & Permissions page, copy the "Bot User OAuth Access Token" (the bottom one)
6. Run the following code (slightly modified version of the code in the docs)

```
from slack_sdk.rtm import RTMClient

# This event runs when the connection is established and shows some connection info
@RTMClient.run_on(event="open")
def show_start(**payload):
    print(payload)

@RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
def say_hello(**payload):
    print(payload)
    data = payload['data']
    web_client = payload['web_client']
    if 'Hello' in data['text']:
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']
        user = data['user']

        web_client.chat_postMessage(
            channel=channel_id,
            text=f"Hi <@{user}>!",
            thread_ts=thread_ts
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    slack_token = "<YOUR TOKEN HERE>"
    rtm_client = RTMClient(token=slack_token)
    rtm_client.start()
```

**Previous answer:**

> Hmm, this is tricky one... According to the docs this only works for "classic" Slack apps, so that might be the first pointer. It explicitly says that you should not upgrade your app. Furthermore, you'll need to set the right permissions (god knows which ones) by selecting the "bot" scope.
>
> Honestly, I haven't been able to get this running. Looks like Slack is getting rid of this connection method, so you might have more luck looking into the "Events API". I know it's not the ideal solution because its not as real-time, but it looks better documented and it will stay around for a while. Another approach could be polling. Its not sexy but it works...
>
> My guess is that your problem is that there is not a valid connection, but there is no proper error handling in the Slack library. The message is printed before you actually connect, so that doesn't indicate anything.